# Default value of commandline parameters when no value is provided

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am using ArgParse for giving commandline parameters in Python.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--quality", type=int,help="enter some quality limit")
args = parser.parse_args()
qual=args.quality

if args.quality:
  qual=0

$ python a.py --quality 

a.py: error: argument --quality: expected one argument
```

In case of no value provided,I want to use it as 0,I also have tried to put it as "default=0" in parser.add_argument,and also with an if statement.But,I get the error above.

Basically,I want to use it as a flag and give a default value in case no value is provided.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `nargs='?'` to allow `--quality` to be used with 0 or 1 value supplied. Use `const=0` to handle `script.py --quality` without a value supplied. Use `default=0` to handle bare calls to `script.py` (without `--quality` supplied).

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--quality", type=int, help="enter some quality limit",
                    nargs='?', default=0, const=0)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

behaves like this:

```
% script.py 
Namespace(quality=0)
% script.py --quality
Namespace(quality=0)
% script.py --quality 1
Namespace(quality=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a loot at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#id1. Simply add the argument `default` to your add_argument call.

`parser.add_argument("--quality", type=int, default=0, nargs='?', help="enter some quality limit")`

If you want to use `--quality` as a flag you should use `action="store_true"`. This will set `args.quality` to `True` if `--quality` is used.

Answer (score -1):

## With `docopt` use `[default: 0]` in docstring

Deliberately ignoring the `argparse` part of your question, here is how you could define default using `docopt`.

With `docopt` you define default value (and almost all the rest) as part of docstring.

First, install `docopt` and for validating values also `schema`

```
$ pip install docopt schema
```

Then write the script `a.py`:

```
"""
Usage:
    a.py [--quality <qlimit>]
    a.py -h

Options:
    --quality=<qlimit>  Quality limit [default: 0]
"""
def main(quality):
    print "FROM MAIN: minimal quality was set to", quality

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    from schema import Schema, And, Use, SchemaError
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print args
    schema = Schema({
        "--quality": 
        And(Use(int), lambda n: 0 <= n, error="<qlimit> must be non-negative integer"),
        "-h": bool
    })
    try:
        args = schema.validate(args)
    except SchemaError as e:
        exit(e)
    quality = args["--quality"]
    main(quality)
```

and use the script, first asking for help string:

```
$ python a.py -h
Usage:
    a.py [--quality <qlimit>]
    a.py -h

Options:
    --quality=<qlimit>  Quality limit [default: 0]
```

Then use it using default value:

```
$ python a.py
{'--quality': '0',
 '-h': False}
FROM MAIN: minimal quality was set to 0
```

setting non-default correct one to 5:

```
$ python a.py --quality 5
{'--quality': '5',
 '-h': False}
FROM MAIN: minimal quality was set to 5
```

trying not allowed negative value:

```
$ python a.py --quality -99
{'--quality': '-99',
 '-h': False}
<qlimit> must be non-negative integer
```

or non integer one:

```
$ python a.py --quality poor
{'--quality': 'poor',
 '-h': False}
<qlimit> must be non-negative integer
```

Note, that as soon as the `validate` step passes, the value for "--quality" key is already converted to `int`.